# Grant access to pod terminal in openshift origin 3.3

Tags: console, openshift-origin

I have a user with "view" role in an specific project.

I would like this user to be able to access "Terminal" option on project PODs through GUI console(now I get an error message saying "Could not connect to the container. Do you have sufficient privileges?").

Which role should I assign to this user? or can I create a custom role with pods/exec access?

Thank you

Comment: You would need to create a custom role.  Note too that terminal access is also gated so that you cannot exec into a container with security settings that you don't have the authority to create - things like hostPath access, running as root, running as privileged.  So you cannot exec into a build container today unless you have cluster admin rights.

Comment: OK Clayton, thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Clayton's answer is correct, you can create a custom role, but you should think carefully about whether `exec` is an appropriate level of power and how you would control the escalation vectors.

If you take a viewer and add grant them exec privileges, that user suddenly becomes the rough equivalent of editor.  He has the power to change the state of the pod which is serving your service and he has the power to see the auto-mounted service account token.  Seeing that token gives him the power of any service account (by default just an image puller), but integrations like jenkins assign edit permission to service accounts.